# ng-repeat filter through key/value pairs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am repeating through a data model that contains key/value pairs. Let's say there are 30 rows, and 5 of them contain the string 'map' in the key.

I want to filter the display to show only those objects that contain the string 'map'. I know this is a filter, however, I am not having much luck with the documentation - none of it deals with ng-repeat on key/values.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
<div class="row" 
    data-ng-repeat="(textKey, textValue) in publisher.update.file">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        <label class="text-right inline" 
            for="file"
            id="textKey">
            {{ textKey }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-align-left small-9 columns">
        <input name="textKey"
            ng-model="publisher.update.lang[textKey]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you not use ng-show? On your element, you can <span ng-show="textValue=='map'"></span>

Comment: ^ That's the one! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can do that with **default** [filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/filter/filter)

doc says:

> Selects a subset of items from **array** and returns it as a new array.

But you can create your own filter to achieve this. here is the example

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.filter('Find', function() {
  return function(input, str) {
    var tmp = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(val, key) {
      if (val.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
        tmp[key] = val;
      }
    });
    return tmp;
  };
})
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-init="test = {test1:'map',test2:'map2',test3:'test'}"></div>

    Search:
    <input ng-model="search" type="text">
    <br>
    <table id="searchTextResults">
      <tr>
        <th>key</th>
        <th>val</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in test| Find: search||'' ">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{val}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```